# ARCore - Get camera facing angle to world forward (-Z axis)

Tags: android, arcore

Is there a way to get the angle that the ARCore camera is facing compared to one of ARCore's axis in Euler angles? I understand that we can get the forward vector the ARCore camera, but I am unsure as to how get the correct angle that could be calculated from this.

Answer (score 0):

Was probably overthinking the problem. Here is a simple way to get the angle the camera is facing to the -Z axis (positive angle is to right of -Z axis). This method could also be used to figure out the angle the camera is facing to a different axis also.

```
// get the camera
Camera arCamera = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getCamera();

// get forward vector of the camera
Vector3 cameraPos = arCamera.getWorldPosition();
Vector3 cameraForward = Vector3.add(cameraPos, arCamera.getForward().scaled(1.0f));
Vector3 forwardVector = Vector3.subtract(cameraForward, cameraPos);
forwardVector = new Vector3(forwardVector.x, 0, forwardVector.z).normalized();

double degreesFromCamToNegZAxis = Vector3.angleBetweenVectors(Vector3.forward(), forwardVector);

// take the dot product between the two vectors
// to see from what side of the -Z axis it is facing
float dotProduct = Vector3.dot(Vector3.right(), forwardVector);

// value is between -1 to 1 
// if negative, forward vector is facing to the right of -Z axis
if (dotProduct < 0) {
    degreesFromCamToNegZAxis = -degreesFromCamToNegZAxis;
}
```

If you want to figure out from a different axis just change the vector to the world you are trying to relate it to like so. Positive angle is to the right of positive Z axis in this example.

```
double degreesFromCamToZAxis = Vector3.angleBetweenVectors(Vector3.back(), forwardVector);

// take the dot product between the two vectors
// to see from what side of the Z axis it is facing
float dotProduct = Vector3.dot(Vector3.left(), forwardVector);

// value is between -1 to 1
// if negative, forward vector is facing to the left of Z axis
if (dotProduct < 0) {
    degreesFromCamToZAxis = -degreesFromCamToZAxis;
}
```

Here is an image that visualizes the coordinate system ARCore uses (same as Android's Sensors).
[ARCore Coordinate System Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dZrU.png)